# В большинстве своем или в своем большинстве?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вопрос по стилистике. Есть выражение, зафиксированное в словарях - в большинстве своем. В статье встретила в этом выражении инверсию слов: в своем большинстве. Вопрос: корректно ли это? Мне почему-то что-то "корябает". ))) Поискала в интернете: даже Познер в своем интервью употребляет выражение с инверсией, а он для меня авторитет. Может у меня просто уже глаз "замылился" и все нормально?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  в большинстве своем. В статье встретила в этом выражении инверсию слов: в своем большинстве.
```

Инверсия здесь как раз "в большинстве своём", а прямой порядок - "в своем большинстве" -определение перед определяемым словом. Так как инверсия - более образное выражение, то его и употребляют в основном, всем нравится, оно стало привычным, но есть приверженцы строгой научной речи, которые стараются использовать нейтральные конструкции, если нет причин для образности, поэтому всё нормально, кому как нравится.

Comment: Спасибо)))

Answer (score 1):

> В статье встретила в этом выражении
>   инверсию слов: в своем большинстве.

И Розенталь с Добромысловым так говорили. Значит, корректно.

См.  https://books.google.ru/books?id=Fdo-AQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%22+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&dq=%22%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%22+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=lpErVYfBMuf7ygOWoIHQBQ&redir_esc=y

[image]